# trailing slashes in 301 redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've tried to look through the multiple mod_rewrite questions, so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

I'm trying set it so that if you go to domain.com/about.php it removes .php and if you go to domain.com/about it simply remains like that.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

So, right now if you go to domain.com/about it displays the page, but if you go to domain.com/about.php it doesn't remove the extension.

Additionally, I have 301 redirects

```
redirect 301 /our-clients http://www.domain.com/about-ourclients
```

That works perfect, but if the user goes to domain.com/our-clients/ with the trailing slash, they are directed to about-ourclients.php

Any advice on how to rewrite my rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove .php ONLY if requested directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\.php\sHTTP/1)
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# remove trailing slash ONLY if it is not an existing folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# rewrite to FILENAME.php if such file does exist and is not a folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

1. It will redirect all direct requests to php files: `/something.php` will be redirected to `/something`
2. Will remove the trailing slash IF requested resource is not directory. So if you requesting `/home/` and you do have such folder, then it will NOT be redirected to `/home`.
3. Will internally rewrite requests to the same named PHP file IF it does exist. If you are requesting `/about` and you have `/about.php` then it will do rewrite; If you have no `/about.php` then nothing happens (well, at least not on these rules -- if you have more rules then such request can be matched later .. or 404 error page will be shown).
4. If you are requesting `/about`, you have `/about.php` and you also have `/about` folder, then request will go into folder. If you do not want this to happen ( `/about` should always be rewritten to `/about.php`) then you need to remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` from last block. But since you have exactly the same condition in your current .htaccess then I assume it is desired behaviour.